# Two dimensional array bug (can't find it)

Tags: java, arrays

I am doing this homework project that produces the pascals triangle but I'm getting an error and I can't find it. I looked it over many times but to me it seems okay, Can someone help me find the bug?

```
public class PascalsTriangle {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] triangle = new int[11][];
    fillIn(triangle);
    print(triangle);
}

public static void fillIn(int[][] triangle) {
    for (int i = 0; i < triangle.size(); i++) {
        triangle[i] = new int[i++];
        triangle[i][0] = 1;
        triangle[i][i] = 1;
        for (int j = 1; j < i; j++) {
            triangle[i][j] = triangle[i-1][j-1] + triangle[i-1][j];
        }
    }
}

public static void print(int[][] triangle) {
    for (int i = 0; i < triangle.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < triangle[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(triangle[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: A compile error because you can't call `.size()` on an array?  Use `.length` instead like in your second method.

Comment: this is what I get. at PascalsTriangle.main(PascalsTriangle.java:5)

Comment: post the **full error message**

Comment: @azurefrog yes that is the error I got confused with two dimensional Arrays and ArrayLists Thank you.

Comment: @mellamokb the error was when I called triangle.size() instead of triangle.length

Comment: You're error should have been `PascalsTriangle.java:10: error: cannot find symbol`.  Since you posted part of a stack trace, I assumed you had fixed the `size` issue already and had gotten the `NullPointerException`.

Comment: I see more problem than using the wrong method. It seems that there is a null pointer exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you have already changed your code to use `length` instead of `size` as the other answer mentions.

When you call this method:

```
public static void fillIn(int[][] triangle) {
    for (int i = 0; i < triangle.length; i++) {
        triangle[i] = new int[i++];                 // this line
        triangle[i][0] = 1;
```

The line pointed out above should be:

```
triangle[i] = new int[i + 1];
```

When you call `i++` the int array will be initialized with length `i` and **then** i will be incremented. You are already incrementing `i` in the declaration of your for loop. So, we take away the `++`.

But then we have another problem. You start the loop at `i = 0`. Then you initialize an array with length `0`. Then you add an element to that array. Something doesn't make sense. What you meant to do was to initialize the array as `int[i + 1]`.

Finally the program displays some lines from Pascal's Triangle:

```
 1 
 1 1 
 1 2 1 
 1 3 3 1 
 1 4 6 4 1 
 1 5 10 10 5 1 
 1 6 15 20 15 6 1 
 1 7 21 35 35 21 7 1 
 1 8 28 56 70 56 28 8 1 
 1 9 36 84 126 126 84 36 9 1 
 1 10 45 120 210 252 210 120 45 10 1
```

Comment: could you explain it. Because i tried by ++i, it's still error.
(dont care about i in loop)

Comment: @tana i added an explanation. If you use `++i`, then you are incrementing `i` an extra time. You only need `i` incremented once and that is in the for-loop statement.

Comment: as I said in my answer, do not use i++ or ++i. Instead, use int[i + 1]

Comment: I got it, the cause is triangle[i][i] = 1 <- it use i. Thank Will Newton

Answer (score 1):

not sure this method exist

> triangle.size()

try

> triangle.length

instead